# Chrome extension: how to call alarm from popup.js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm doing chrome extension. On click button in popup.html a call scote to call alarm ffrom background.js.

popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
    checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        //call alarm
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "alert"}, function(response) {
            //NONE response, why?
            console.log(response.farewell);
            alert("response:" + response.farewell);
        });
        document.getElementById('checkPage').innerHTML = "SET"; 
   }, false);
}, false);
```

background.js:

```
//alarm
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.greeting == "alert"){
            alert("alert alarm");
            sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
        }
    }
);
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "AlarmText",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": ["alarms", "http://my-url.com"],

    "icons": { "128": "icons/icon128.png",
               "64": "icons/icon64.png",
               "32": "icons/icon32.png" },  

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Alarm test",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>popup</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="out">???</div>
    <button id="checkPage">Refresh</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is wrong? In call alarm: chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "alert"}, function(response) is not response

Comment: You send `hello` but the background script expects `alert`, voting to close as a typo question.

Comment: Reapair, but still not work

Comment: Update the code in the question then.

Comment: Post your manifest and popup.html.

Comment: Add manifest and popup.html